# Can't Install Android Studio In Manjaro (Arch) Linux

Tags: linux, installation, arch-linux, manjaro, pacman

I was just trying to install Android Studio in Manjaro Linux with yaourt but it returns this error all the time:

```
/usr/lib/yaourt/pkgbuild.sh: line 219: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device
/usr/lib/yaourt/pkgbuild.sh: line 74: echo: write error: No space left on device
cat: write error: No space left on device
/usr/lib/yaourt/pkgbuild.sh: line 76: echo: write error: No space left on device
/usr/lib/yaourt/pkgbuild.sh: line 77: echo: write error: No space left on device
/usr/lib/yaourt/pkgbuild.sh: line 78: echo: write error: No space left on device
/usr/lib/yaourt/pkgbuild.sh: line 79: echo: write error: No space left on device
/usr/lib/yaourt/pkgbuild.sh: line 80: echo: write error: No space left on device
/usr/lib/yaourt/pkgbuild.sh: line 81: echo: write error: No space left on device
/usr/lib/yaourt/pkgbuild.sh: line 82: echo: write error: No space left on device
/usr/lib/yaourt/pkgbuild.sh: line 83: echo: write error: No space left on device
/usr/lib/yaourt/pkgbuild.sh: line 84: echo: write error: No space left on device
/usr/lib/yaourt/pkgbuild.sh: line 85: echo: write error: No space left on device
==> ERROR:  is not available for the 'x86_64' architecture.
==> ERROR: pkgname is not allowed to be empty.
==> ERROR: pkgver is not allowed to be empty.
==> ERROR: pkgrel is not allowed to be empty.
Unable to read PKGBUILD
/usr/lib/yaourt/aur.sh: line 210: cd: /home/lvlzyro/Downloads/android-studio: No such file or directory
```

Inside of PKGBUILD:

```
pkgname=android-studio
pkgver=3.3.2.0
pkgrel=1
_build=182.5314842
pkgdesc="The official Android IDE (Stable branch)"
arch=('i686' 'x86_64')
url="http://tools.android.com/"
license=('APACHE')
makedepends=('unzip')
depends=('alsa-lib' 'freetype2' 'libxrender' 'libxtst')
optdepends=('gtk2: GTK+ look and feel'
            'libgl: emulator support')
options=('!strip')
source=("https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/$pkgver/android-studio-ide-$_build-linux.zip"
        "$pkgname.desktop")
sha256sums=('8257d3eab61c3da088e26689888a13e53e210c109a4e775ed71158b4471bb06a'
            '73cd2dde1d0f99aaba5baad1e2b91c834edd5db3c817f6fb78868d102360d3c4')

if [ "$CARCH" = "i686" ]; then
    depends+=('java-environment')
fi

package() {
  cd $srcdir/$pkgname

  # Install the application
  install -d $pkgdir/{opt/$pkgname,usr/bin}
  cp -a bin gradle lib jre plugins $pkgdir/opt/$pkgname
  ln -s /opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh $pkgdir/usr/bin/$pkgname

  # Add the icon and desktop file
  install -Dm644 bin/studio.png $pkgdir/usr/share/pixmaps/$pkgname.png
  install -Dm644 $srcdir/$pkgname.desktop $pkgdir/usr/share/applications/$pkgname.desktop

  chmod -R ugo+rX $pkgdir/opt
}
```

Comment: Please check your free disk space and permissions.

Comment: I just checked it but there is no problems about permissions and there is 230G free space.

Comment: Then I guess your filesystem is write protected, wrongly mounted or has other serious issues. Which filesystem are you running?

Comment: How about your `/tmp` directory? How much space you have left there? Could you check that please? See: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/tmp-fills-up-way-too-fast-acting-glitchy/39960

Comment: I don't know how but a few days ago I just tried to install it again and I just worked. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yeah, good. You're welcome!